# can't get array value with file_get_contents() , but work with local file

Tags: php, json, decode

JSON link: http://vgmdb.info/album/79?format=json

Code I have tried:

```
$string = file_get_contents("http://vgmdb.info/album/79?format=json");
$json_a=json_decode($string,true);
$getit = $json_a['release_price']['price'];
echo $getit ;
```

But I get a blank result. Then I try to download the file and upload to my server:

```
$string = file_get_contents("jsonfile.json");
$json_a=json_decode($string,true);
$getit = $json_a['release_price']['price'];
echo $getit ;
```

Its show the price value. So how to get price value without download the json file first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried in localhost and I got:

> **Warning**: file_get_contents(http://vgmdb.info/album/79?format=json):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal
>   Server Error

This is an hint, so you should **always** enable your errors when you debug your code.

A http `500` code is an internal error of that server. I just tried to add an User-Agent to the request, and it worked:

```
$options = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0\r\n"
  )
);

$string = file_get_contents("http://vgmdb.info/album/79?format=json", false, stream_context_create($options));
$json_a=json_decode($string,true);
$getit = $json_a['release_price']['price'];
echo $getit ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The author of vgmdb.info has fixed the bug that results from a missing User-Agent header. The original code works now.

Answer (score 0):

It can be because of:

```
in php.ini is disabled to file_get_contents gets data from url-s
```

Answer (score 0):

URL can be used as a filename with this function if the [fopen wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) have been enabled. See fopen() for more details on how to specify the filename

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use curl:

```
$url = 'http://vgmdb.info/album/79?format=json';
//
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0' );
$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
$json = json_decode($response);

//result
echo 'price: '.$json->release_price->price;
```

The response give you one object like:

```
//part of object
"release_date": "1999-11-20",
"release_events": [],
"release_price": {
    "currency": "JPY",
    "price": 2854.0
 },
```